# Different rgba blend algorithm in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

They looks different... quite different on *Chrome* and *Firefox*.
Does anyone know what's the problem here?
Did I make some error or *Chrome* has some special blend algorithm?

What I see on *Chrome*:

[image: Chrome]

What I see on *Firefox*:

[image]

update: turn off the hardware acceleration on Chrome fix that for me..
But that's not a fix...

```css
.root {
 position: relative;
 margin: 100px 100px;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 background: rgba(0, 200, 0, 1);
}

.square {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.square1 {
 left: -15px;
 background: rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.5);
 z-index: 1;
}

.square-ref {
 top: -60px;
 background: rgba(100, 100, 0, 1);
 z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="root">
   <div class="square square1"></div>
   <div class="square square2"></div>
   <div class="square square-ref"></div>
  </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: it looks the same in firefox and chrome for me though

Comment: probably your screen configuration?

Comment: ohh I see, what is your chrome version? I don't have issue in V71.0.3578.98

Comment: @kukkuz Oh! Maybe the version matters... Mine is Chrome/71.0.3578.98

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks! But I didn't find any related setting in chrome....

Answer (score 0):

Finally solve this issue..
There is some color profile issue within the chrome https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4216362

After change the `Force color profile` to `sRGB` in `Chrome://flags`, everything looks fine now.